# Is there a way to load multiple renderings in homepage/dashboard parallel in Sitecore 9.1?

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api, performance-optimization, performance

Home page has about 15 renderings with each controller rendering calling different API for analytical data (external systems for graph,charts ,summarized data) hosted on Sitecore 9.1

Average max time taken by some API response is 8 sec and for some it is less than 2 sec.

But when I add logs for each of the controller method of rendering for respective API call,
 it shows each rendering is called sequentially and time taken is  2 mins to load the page (12:35 it started and 12:37 when last rendering is loaded)

Query :- Is there a way to load the rendering Parallel so that max time taken is 8 sec?

Comment: Why don't you render the page without components which use 3rd party APIs and then call with jQuery to get the components?

Comment: Also if the data you are showing is not change frequently then you can use caching.

Comment: Data is dynamic, based on like ODS data , sales data , summary data

Comment: I would go for the approach Marek mentioned - get the data with javascript so you can render the page much faster (and the javascript can be done async).

Comment: one observation was the Renderings are loaded sequentially , and menu is data driven so is the header where the user rewards are displayed where each is a API call.